# Using grouper for two groups or more in gives the wrong plot pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                      'date':['2019-01-01 07:59:54','2019-01-01 08:00:07','2019-01-01 08:00:07',
                              '2019-01-02 08:00:14','2019-01-02 08:00:16','2019-01-02 08:00:24',
                              '2019-01-03 08:02:38','2019-01-03 08:50:14'],
                      'machine':['A','A','B','C','B','C','D','D'],
                      'group':['Grind','Grind','Weld','Grind','Weld','Grind','Weld','Weld']})
my_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
my_df
    id  date                machine group
0   1   2019-01-01 07:59:54 A       Grind
1   2   2019-01-01 08:00:07 A       Grind
2   3   2019-01-01 08:00:07 B       Weld
3   4   2019-01-02 08:00:14 C       Grind
4   5   2019-01-02 08:00:16 B       Weld
5   6   2019-01-02 08:00:24 C       Grind
6   7   2019-01-03 08:02:38 D       Weld
7   8   2019-01-03 08:50:14 D       Weld
```

I have tried this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
my_df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D'), 'group'])['machine'].count().plot(ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d %m'))
plt.show()
```

But it gives me this wrong plot:

[image]

Please, could you help me on what I am doing wrong with my code? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What plot do you _want_?

Comment: I want a plot with two lines, one with 'Grind' and the other with 'Weld'. And you can see in the X axis that the day is repeated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) `group` after [`groupby count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) to put groups as columns so they plot in separate lines:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
# Create Plot DataFrame
plot_df = (
    my_df.groupby([
        pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D'), 'group'
    ])['machine'].count().unstack('group')
)
# Plot on ax
plot_df.plot(ax=ax)
# Set Display
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d %m'))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

`plot_df`:

```
group       Grind  Weld
date                   
2019-01-01    2.0   1.0
2019-01-02    2.0   1.0
2019-01-03    NaN   2.0
```

Plot:

[image: plot]

---

Data and imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, dates as mdates

my_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'date': ['2019-01-01 07:59:54', '2019-01-01 08:00:07',
             '2019-01-01 08:00:07',
             '2019-01-02 08:00:14', '2019-01-02 08:00:16',
             '2019-01-02 08:00:24',
             '2019-01-03 08:02:38', '2019-01-03 08:50:14'],
    'machine': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
    'group': ['Grind', 'Grind', 'Weld', 'Grind', 'Weld',
              'Grind', 'Weld', 'Weld']
})
my_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['date'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Henry Ecker, you know it was quite difficult for me to guess what was happening with the plot, and your answer is great. Hope it helps other python learners too! Have a great day!